# What happend when a macro variable with percent symbol as its value in %put statement?

Tags: sas

I happened to see a piece of code:

```
%let x=%;
%let y=B;
%put &x A&y;
```

The output at log window is:

```
% AB  AB
```

I don't understand why this output. I thought it should be: % AB.
I write some test codes and try to figure it out, but don't have a clear explanation as so far.

---

More test:

```
%let x=%;
%let y=B;
%put % A&y;
LOG: % AB

%put &x AB;
LOG: % AB

%put &x A &y;
LOG: % A B

%let x=%nrstr(%%);
%put &x A&y;
LOG: % AB

option symbolgen mlogic;
%put &x A&y;
LOG:
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X resolves to %
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y resolves to B
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y resolves to B
% AB  AB

%put &x A&x;
LOG: 
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X resolves to %
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X resolves to %
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X resolves to %
Infinite loop of the last sentence.
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I didn't believe this until I tried it. And then I thought, 'hopefully it's a weird bug in %PUT.'  But I can replicate it in a DATA step assignment statement, so looks like a macro resolution bug to me. As you showed, SYMBOLGEN even shows Y resolving twice.

```
1    %let x=%;
2    %let y=B;
3
4    data _null_ ;
5     x ="&x A&y" ;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X resolves to %
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y resolves to B
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable Y resolves to B
6     put x= ;
7    run ;

x=% AB AB
```

I will cross post to SAS-L to engage more minds. You might try sending in to SAS tech support to see what they think.

Comment: Thank you Quentin, I'll look for an official anwser.

Comment: I started a thread on communities.sas.com.  No big insights yet.  Just agreement that it's a bug triggered by the bare % sign https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Macro-variable-resolution-bug-with-sign/m-p/891680

Comment: Thank you Quentin, I see a lot of meaningful discussion.

Answer (score 2):

It is an old bug in SAS, it is there in SAS 9.2 for example.

Using %SUPERQ() to quote the % makes it go away.

```
%let x=%;
%let x=%superq(x);
%let y=B;
data _null_ ;
  x ="&x A&y" ;
  put x= ;
run ;
```

Result

```
x=% AB
```

Comment: I agree with you now, I asked SAS IT and they reply it is a known bug but not fixed due to some complicated reason. There is also a solution: https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p0pnc7p9n4h6g5n16g6js048nhfl.htm

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for viewing or discussing on this question. I have asked SAS IT support and it turns out this is a known bug but not fixed yet.
If you see this [webpage](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p0pnc7p9n4h6g5n16g6js048nhfl.htm), you can find a workaround:

> There is an issue that can occur when a macro variable value ends with % and, at resolution, is followed immediately by a special character and another macro variable. In that case, the special character and the second macro variable value might print twice. The following example illustrates this issue:
>
> %let var1=ABC%;
> %let var2=DEF;
> %put &var1.#&var2.;
> Here is the result:
>
> ABC%#DEF#DEF
> To resolve the issue in this case, use the %NRSTR function and two percent signs in the VAR1 macro variable assignment, as shown in the following example:
>
> %let var1=%nrstr(ABC%%);
> This masks the % in the VAR1 macro variable value, which resolves the issue.
>
> Note: The %STR function does not mask % and, as a result, does not resolve this issue.

This bug fixing process have a more severe impact on the processing of tokens and the change was backed out since there is a fairly easy workaround available in documentation.

Comment: Thanks for following up with SAS support and sharing the results.   If you want to post this answer over at communities.sas.com as well, I'll mark it as correct there, just to close the discussion.